# Error encounter TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple

Tags: python, jupyter, networkx, data-science

Im following a tutorial on a program to visualize facebook connections and I keep getting "TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple" and I don't know how to fix this issue

```
colors = cl.scales['12']['qual']['Paired']
def scatter_nodes(pos, labels=None, color='rgb(152, 0, 0)', size=8, opacity=1):

    trace = Scatter(x=[], 
                    y=[],  
                    mode='markers', 
                    marker=Marker(
        showscale=False,
        colorscale='Greens',
        reversescale=True,
        color=[], 
        size=10,
    line=dict(width=0)))
    for nd in nodeID:
        trace['x'].append(pos[nd][0])
        trace['y'].append(pos[nd][1])
        color = colors[part[nd] % len(colors)]
        trace['marker']['color'].append(color)
    attrib=dict(name='', text=labels , hoverinfo='text', opacity=opacity) # a dict of Plotly node attributes
    trace=dict(trace, **attrib)# concatenate the dict trace and attrib
    trace['marker']['size']=size

    return trace 

def scatter_edges(G, pos, line_color='#a3a3c2', line_width=1, opacity=.2):
    trace = Scatter(x=[], 
                    y=[], 
                    mode='lines'
                   )
    for edge in G.edges():
        trace['x'] += [pos[edge[0]][0],pos[edge[1]][0], None]
        trace['y'] += [pos[edge[0]][1],pos[edge[1]][1], None]  
        trace['hoverinfo']='none'
        trace['line']['width']=line_width
        if line_color is not None: # when it is None a default Plotly color is used
            trace['line']['color']=line_color
    return trace          

labels = []

for nd in nodeID:
      labels.append('{} ({})'.format(nd, part[nd],))

trace1 = scatter_edges(G, pos, line_width=0.25)
trace2 = scatter_nodes(pos, labels=labels)
```

I tried changing it to parenthesis but that didn't work either.

Error Statement

```
 TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-7db6d16fa847> in <module>
----> 1 trace1 = scatter_edges(G, pos, line_width=0.25)
      2 trace2 = scatter_nodes(pos, labels=labels)

<ipython-input-23-0e8ff4c52f3c> in scatter_edges(G, pos, line_color, line_width, opacity)
      5                    )
      6     for edge in G.edges():
----> 7         trace['x'] += [pos[edge[0]][0],pos[edge[1]][0], None]
      8         trace['y'] += [pos[edge[0]][1],pos[edge[1]][1], None]
      9         trace['hoverinfo']='none'

TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple
```

Comment: I posted a screenshot of the error statement

Comment: When someone posts a comment for clarification, you should edit your question, just as you did. Be sure that the edit still makes the entire question coherent. You should also post the error message as text, not as an image.

Comment: Since you are new to Stack Overflow, you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @ukwu13 Please edit your code further so that anyone can copy/paste it and run it themselves and get the exact same error that you are asking about.

Comment: what is initial value of trace ['x']

Comment: You are using `return trace` but I do not see any function definition in your code. Moreover, you do not define `trace` anywhere in the code.

Comment: I apologize! I didnt post everything because it was long and was trying to keep minimal code

Comment: first build x,y, colour, then scatter

Comment: It would be more proper and sound way first build x, y, colour etc then create Scater

Comment: Ideally 'minimal' code is complete enough to run, and show the error.  If I can't run your example on my computer, I can only read the code, and 'run' it in my head, guessing what various values are.  That's a tedious and error prone process.

Comment: @hpaulj should I edit the post and add all the code?

Comment: Probably not.  I suppose a link to the tutorial might help.  And an explanation of what you have changed (assuming the tutorial does actually run).  I suspect the tutorial, and your test, depends on one or more external data file (text, image, url etc).  It's easiest to give help with the code is compact and self contained.

Comment: @hpaulj https://ndres.me/post/friend-graph-tutorial/  yes it does depend on an external data file. It created a pickle file

Comment: @hpaulj i don't know if you had asked for the tutorial because you were about to try it out but if so, any luck?

Answer (score 1):

`trace['x']` is tuple

`[pos[edge[0]][0],pos[edge[1]][0], None]` is a list, hence the error

You cannot concatenate a list to tuple directly. But you can tranform/adjust data to same type. In one direction or another. For instance,
you can 1) build list from tuple 2) then concatenate another list(s) 3) transform the result to a tuple

Comment: that is hard to guess what is initial value of trace['x']. It is probably tuple which breaks the code. Converting it to a list might fix current bug yet more error might follow or not depending on what you are doing

Comment: Converting the list literal to a tuple literal will fix the error. Of course who knows if that's the only problem?

Comment: yup it is true give it a try

Comment: @Code-Apprentice tuple(trace['x'] += [pos[edge[0]][0],pos[edge[1]][0], None]) ?

Comment: trace['x'] += tuple ([pos[edge[0]][0],pos[edge[1]][0], None]) )

Comment: @Serge OMG it worked! But now I get a new error 
---> 23         trace['x'].append(pos[nd][0])
     24         trace['y'].append(pos[nd][1])
     25         color = colors[part[nd] % len(colors)]

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: you can try proceed in the same manner but replace append with += tuple(...)

Comment: @Serge trace['x'].+=tuple((pos[nd][0])) like that?

Comment: @Serge sorry to keep bothering you. After those changes I get this error now 
      1 trace1 = scatter_edges(G, pos, line_width=0.25)
----> 2 trace2 = scatter_nodes(pos, labels=labels)

<ipython-input-12-79e4c0d259a0> in scatter_nodes(pos, labels, color, size, opacity)
     21     line=dict(width=0)))
     22     for nd in nodeID:
---> 23         trace['x']+=tuple(...)
     24         trace['y']+=tuple(...)
     25         color = colors[part[nd] % len(colors)]

TypeError: 'ellipsis' object is not iterable

Comment: He did not mean for you to use `(...)` literally.  The three dots means, 'fill in your own values'.  In Python '...', is called an `ellipsis`, and has special meaning in indexing.  That's not the intent here.

Comment: @ukwu13 For your original error you can do either `trace['x'] += tuple ([pos[edge[0]][0],pos[edge[1]][0], None])` or just `trace['x'] += (pos[edge[0]][0],pos[edge[1]][0], None)`. Brackets signify a list and parentheses signify a tuple. However, since you are later appending, you should probably keep this line of code as it is and fix `trace['x']` to be a list in the first place. I suggest that you read about the differences between lists and tuples in python.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I did and learned about the differences such as immutability